# Interaction between Spring Boot and JUnit 5 -- must use the overall artifacts not the individuals?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

This question has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862349/spring-boot-starter-test-with-junit-5)), but my observation was not the same as those previously reported.

I noticed that to get JUnit 5 to work, I must include the overall JUnit 5 artifact

```
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1')
```

If I, instead, included the individual artifacts, then the JUnit test would not be picked up

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.3.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.1')
```

Has anyone seen something similar before?

(I also tried this with a non-Spring-Boot project -- in that case it was okay to include the individual artifacts.  This was causing a lot of confusion.)

Here I am showing the result with gradle, but I have had similar result with maven too.

I am using `Gradle 5.4.1`, `Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE`, and `JUnit 5.5.1`

I am including the full `build.gradle` and the test class below

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1')

//  testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.3.1')
//  testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0')
//  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
//  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
//  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.1')
//  testImplementation('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.1')

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**DemoApplicationTest.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void failMe() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

}
```

Note that in this case I was expecting an exception be thrown in the test method `failMe()` -- so as to prove that the test method had been picked up by the runner and was not silently ignored.

Comment: Don’t know if that’s the reason but your versions don’t fit. With Jupiter 5.5.1 you should use platform runner and launcher 1.5.1.

Comment: Thanks!  That explains it.  I think I now understand better and I provided my own answer below.  Please see if you agree.  By the way, I think what is needed is the launcher.  The runner is not needed in this case.  Do you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the hint from @johanneslink (in the comment of the opening question), now I think I understand better the issues:

**It is better to use the aggregate artifact**

```
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1')
```

**If you really want to use the individual artifacts, make sure their versions are compatible**

This combination would work

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
```

But not this

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.3.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
```

(The other three artifacts are not relevant so I am omitting them here.  For example, according to the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#appendix)

> `junit-platform-runner`
>
> Runner for executing tests and test suites on the JUnit Platform in a JUnit 4 environment.

and is not relevant here.)

Comment: The problem you’re facing is one of compatibility. Platform and Jupiter versions upgrade side by side with 1.x.y of platform corresponding to 5.x.y of Jupiter. The JUnit platform is (mostly) backwards compatible, that means you can run test engines build for older versions of the platform on newer versions.  Making a platform forwards compatible is a much harder task, often not worth the effort.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with SpringBoot and using the aggregate artifact solved the problem for me. In my case I only used  the engine and api artifacts (same version) as I saw on a baeldung tutorial. I still have not fully understood what the problem was.