# JUnit Jupiter 5.5.1 depends on JUnit Platform 1.3.2?

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have an impression that `JUnit Jupiter 5.5.1` does not like `JUnit Platform 1.3.1`.  If both are specified in gradle dependency, then all JUnit 5 tests would just be ignored.  See my previous [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437511/1168041) on this.  For example, I think the following combination would NOT work:

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.3.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
```

Instead, I must use the following combination.  That is, `JUnit Platform Launcher` must be `1.5.1` not `1.3.1`:

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1')
```

That was a few months ago.  Today, I just realized that in my project, those JUnit 5 tests are being ignored again.  Upon deeper inspection, however, I found the following dependency chain:

```
+--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1 -> 5.3.2
|    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0
|    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.1.1
|    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.3.2
|    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0
|    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.1 -> 5.3.2
|         +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0
|         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2 (*)
```

Does anyone know why here `Junit Jupiter 5.5.1` would depend on `JUnit Platform Commons 1.3.2`

**Update with more info from dependencyInsight**

Based on the discussion here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952415/1168041) and in [discuss.gradle.org](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependency-report/3647), the `->` means there has been a "conflict resolution" of dependency and we could use the task `dependencyInsight` to gain more insight.  I did that but still I could not quite know how to interpret the result.

```
clee@WS00509 MINGW64 ~/pg/dhpv2a (pg/gradle-6)
$ ./gradlew :profiler:dependencyInsight --configuration testCompileClasspath --dependency org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter

> Task :profiler:dependencyInsight
org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library (not requested)

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1
\--- testCompileClasspath

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library (not requested)

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.2
     \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1 (requested org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.1)
          \--- testCompileClasspath

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1 -> 5.3.2
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1
     \--- testCompileClasspath

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.2 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library (not requested)

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.1 -> 5.3.2
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1
     \--- testCompileClasspath

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

My ultimate goal is just to get my JUnit 5 tests running.  Any ideas on how to do that?

**Update 2 -- added gradle files**

The gradle build files (and gradle.properties) are listed on this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/leeyuiwah-sl/9d8245abb1f75623c5f2e1e3c6d06650).  This is a multi-project build, so the root directory has `build.gradle` and one of the sub-project `profiler` has `profiler.gradle`

Comment: Please provide your complete Gradle file. The version downgrade must happen due to some other dependencies or plugins.

Comment: @johanneslink -- Thanks!  I added three gradle files to the opening question.

Comment: You're using Spring Boot 2.1.4, which has a dependency on JUnit jupiter 5.3.2 in its BOM. See https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.4.RELEASE.pom. Upgrade to the latest Spring Boot, or configure the dependency management plugin to use the version of junit jupiter that you want.

Comment: @JBNizet -- Wow!  Thanks!  I should have caught that myself.  Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions)