# Error TestEngine with ID "junit-vintage" failed to discover tests when using Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a group project and am trying to run a test. When running it I get the error in the file along with org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name ...

I've tried invalidating caches and restarting and I've also tried re-importing the pom.xml file but I'm still getting the error when trying to run a test.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using intellij IDEA 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)

Error that Intellij is showing

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: <ommitted>
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.lambda$lazyLoadJavaClass$0(MethodSelector.java:156)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.lazyLoadJavaClass(MethodSelector.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.getJavaClass(MethodSelector.java:135)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:34)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$0(MethodSelectorResolver.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:30)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: Do you have the correct dependencies installed? Take a look at this one: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000038750-Can-t-find-tests-JUnit-5-

Comment: @DasSoftware ah it turns out I opened my project incorrectly and there was a path conflict! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use 'junit-vintage' is better remove from the springboot dependency... in some version this module is not executing...
For me resolved.

see this Question:
[spring-boot-starter-test with JUnit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862349/spring-boot-starter-test-with-junit-5)